# Flash Symbol to Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5

Can I get action script code from a symbol in adobe flash?
I have applied various colors and gradients in stage of adobe flash professional.
Now I want to use this code in adobe flash builder for my project.
Any suggestion so that i can use this in flash builder?

Comment: Not sure i follow you. Do you want to use graphics from flash pro in flash builder or actionscript from flash pro in flash builder?

Comment: You can move this code that you are using into the Class for the Symbol, either in the constructor or exposed through a custom method. You're not going to be able to edit code exported with the Symbol in the SWF or SWC so you might want to consider moving it wholly into the Flash Builder project files instead of baking it in.